# How to simply return a String using Apache Camel REST DSL

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, apache-camel, camel-rest

I'm trying to use the Apache Camel REST DSL to create a simple REST API that just is supposed to return a String when called.

However, while the code below was once working, the API seems to have changed

```
rest().get("/hello-world").produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).route()
      .setBody(constant("Welcome to apache camel test ")).endRest();
```

**route()** does not exist anymore in **Apache Camel 3.17.0**

[image]

I've also tried

```
rest("/say")
    .get("/hello")
    .responseMessage(200, "Hello World");
```

But this returns an empty String instead of "Hello World"

The only thing that worked so far is by creating an extra route

```
rest("/say")
    .get("/hello")
    .to("direct:build-return-message");

from("direct:build-return-message")
    .setBody(simple("Hello World"));
```

But this can't be the preferred way.

**How would you now set the response body with the latest API?**

Comment: Whats the problem calling direct consumer endpoints? They can be treated like functions in camel anyways.  My guess is that they've just wanted to move all route defining outside REST DSL to simplify things either for users or for themselves.

Comment: @PasiÖsterman one extra route for just returning a string feels to complex to be true, but maybe you are right.

Answer (score 1):

While you can no longer define a simple route that returns a string in Rest-DSL you can use camels [language component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/language-component.html) to achieve something similar using constants, simple language or by using a file in resources folder.

```java
rest("/api")
    .description("Some description")
    .get("/constant")
        .produces("text/plain")
        .to("language:constant:Hello world")
    .get("/simple")
        .produces("text/html")
        // Usage {{host}}:{{port}}/api/simple?name=Bob
        .to("language:simple:<html><body><h1>hello ${headers.name}</h1></body></html>")
    .get("/resource")
        .produces("text/html")
        // Displays project/src/main/resources/pages/hello.html
        .to("language:constant:resource:classpath:pages/hello.html")
;
```

It's unfortunate that examples for language-component are quite sparse as it looks like handy tool for bunch of little things.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe ?

```
rest()
    .get("/hello")
    .route()
    .process( e -> e.getMessage().setBody("Hello World") ) ;
```

Comment: This is exactly what is not working for me with Camel 3.17.0, as the .route() method does not exist. See the screenshot. Putting produces() in front of it makes no difference.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to return a string without introducing an extra sub-route

Comment: That's in fact what I'm trying. Simplest form of just returning a string with the rest DSL. In theory your example looks perfect, but does not work because route() does not exist. Which Camel version do you use?